# Generic function to returning value from query with type T passed parameters

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio

I have this code below, the var name `varCampo` when returned null causes an "invalid type cast" error when using different versions of Delphi.  I have tried 10.3 and 11.2.

In Delphi 10.3, when using, eg:

```
var codigo: integer;

codigo := RetornaCampoTabela<integer>(['a'], ['teste'], 'description', 'Id');
```

When executing the code and `varCampo = null`, Delphi 10.3 returns 0 (zero), which is correct, but in Delphi 11.2 I get "INVALID TYPE CAST".

How to solve this code so it works in all versions of Delphi?

```pascal
class function TDBUtilsController.RetornaCampoTabela<T>(aCamposWhere: array of string; aValuesWhere: array of Variant; ATabela, ARetorno: string): T;
var
  Statement: IDBStatement;
  ResultSet: IDBResultSet;
  varCampo : Variant;
  sSql, sWhere, saux : string;
  I : Integer;
  valResult: TValue;
begin
  if Length(aValuesWhere) <> Length(aCamposWhere) then
  begin
    Application.MessageBox('Parâmetros não conferem', 'Array inválido', MB_OK + MB_ICONERROR);
    Abort;
  end;

  sSql := 'SELECT ' + ARetorno +  ' AS CAMPO FROM ' +  ATabela +  ' ';
  sWhere := ' WHERE ';
  for i := 0 to  Length( aValuesWhere ) -1 do
  begin
    case VarType(aValuesWhere[i]) of
      varString, varUString: saux := QuotedStr( VarToStr( aValuesWhere[i] ) );
    else
      saux := VarToStr( aValuesWhere[i] );
    end;
    if i > 0 then
      sWhere := sWhere + '  AND ' + aCamposWhere[I] + ' = ' +  saux
    else
      sWhere := sWhere + aCamposWhere[I] + ' = ' +  saux ;
  end;
  sSql := sSql + sWhere;
  try
    Statement := AIDBConn.CreateStatement;
    Statement.SetSQLCommand(sSql );
    ResultSet := Statement.ExecuteQuery;
    varCampo  := ResultSet.GetFieldValue('CAMPO');

    valResult := TValue.FromVariant(varCampo);
    Result    := TValue.From<T>( valResult.AsType<T> ).AsType<T>;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      raise Exception.Create('Erro ao buscar campo: ' + ARetorno  +
           '  da tabela: ' +  ATabela  + sLineBreak + e.Message );
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I tried to use `case` for detecting the datatype `T` and return according to `T` passed into the function, eg:

```
if varIsNull(varCampo) then
begin
  case getTypeInfo(T) of
    tkInteger: Result := TValue.From<Integer>(0)
  end else
  begin
    Result := TValue.From<T>( valResult.AsType<T> ).AsType<T>;
  end
```

I don't want this type of code, I want generic code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you involving `TValue` at all? The compiler already knows how to implicitly convert `Variant` to various types, including integers. If `varCampo` is `null`, just return `Default(T)` instead, otherwise return the `Variant` as-is and let the compiler decide how to convert it, eg:

```pascal
varCampo := ResultSet.GetFieldValue('CAMPO');
if VarIsNull(varCampo) then
  Result := Default(T)
else
  Result := varCampo;
```

**UPDATE**: apparently the compiler doesn't like the latter implicit conversion. So, you are right, you will have to go through `TValue`. However, your usage is too verbose, you don't need to create a 2nd `TValue` from a value you have already converted from another `TValue`. Your usage of `TValue` can be simplified:

```pascal
if varIsNull(varCampo) then begin
  Result := Default(T);
end else
begin
  valResult := TValue.FromVariant(varCampo);
  Result := valResult.AsType<T>;
end;
```

Or simpler:

```pascal
if varIsNull(varCampo) then
  Result := Default(T)
else
  Result := TValue.FromVariant(varCampo).AsType<T>;
```

Comment: Result := varCampo i get error converting variant to T type, have any solution for  this or my code is correct?
Result  := TValue.From<T>( valResult.AsType<T> ).AsType<T>;

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting, and is it a compile-time error or a runtime error? No, what you have is not correct, it is too verbose. There is no point in creating a 2nd `TValue`. If you insist on using `TValue`, at least simplify it, eg: `Result := TValue.FromVariant(varCampo).AsType<T>;` However, note that `TValue` is designed to mirror the compiler's implicit conversions only. `Variant` conversions are more flexible.

Comment: i get error on compilation time in the line:
Result := varCampo; 
error convertion , incompatible types T and Variant. Because my function returns T Type.

The compiler says Variant is not a T type

Comment: @Gilmar hmm, apparently I already encountered this exact same error 2 years ago on another forum: [Variant to generic T, how?](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/2694-variant-to-generic-t-how/), but without resolution. Did you try the change I suggested above?

Comment: yes, i tryed, so delphi not compile, because variant and T are incompatibles types